# How do I make a new column with a set value based on IF AND in two other columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset `data` where the first column `A` contains numbers between 0 and 12, and the second column `B` contains numbers between 0 and 962784. I want to make a new column `C` which follows this rule -> If `A` is 0 AND `B` is greater than 1, make `C` = 1, if not make C = 0. The data set would look as follows:

```
 A        B C
 0        0 0
 0       40 1
12        0 0
 6 40000000 0
```

How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data$C <- ifelse(data$A == 0 & data$B > 1, 1, 0)
```